# How to select the values dynamically from select box based on the previous select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am sorry if i cannot make you understand.

I have two tables where the first table contains categories and the next one contains sub-categories and i have another table item where i have has_and_belongs_to_many relation with sub-category table. When i create a new item, i have to display the categories in the first select box and based on the selection, the sub-categories has to be displayed in another select box and the value has to be added. I have already another like shown below

```
<%= collection_select :item, :sub_category_ids, SubCategory.find(:all, :conditions => ["category_id = 7"], :order => 'sub_category_name ASC'), :id, :sub_category_name, { :selected => @item.sub_category_ids }, { :multiple => true, :name => 'item[sub_category_ids][]' } -%>
```

and now i want to add this one like
[image]
along with that. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use AJAX to achieve what you want.

You would want to use Javascript to watch the first drop down value. When that value changes, you would want to make an ajax call to retrieve the values of the second drop down, then fill the second dropbox based on the AJAX response

Comment: ok and how can i add the value of sub-categories to has_many_and_belongs_to? because when i use <%= f.collection_select :item, :sub_category_ids, SubCategory.all.collect {|p| [ p.sub_category_name, p.id ] }, :prompt => 'Please select sub category' %> it displays expected array(got srting) error